# How can I correctly close this JQuery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, jquery-dialog

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and JQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a page I have this dialog:

```
<div id="dialogReject" title="">
    <table style="visibility: hidden;" id="rifiutaTable" border="0" class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 100%!important">
        <tbody style="background-color: #ffffff;">
            <tr>
                <td style="font: 16px Verdana,Geneva,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif !important">Inserire note di rifiuto</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea style="visibility: hidden;" rows="5" cols="70" id="myRejectNote"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Rifiuta" onclick="rifiuta()"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

that I think is created by this JQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    larghezza = '950px';
    lunghezza = '470px';
    lunghezza2 = '530px';
    $("#dialogReject").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         //width:'335px',
         width:'600px',
         modal: true,
         show: {        
             effect: "blind",
             duration: 500      
         },
         hide: { 
             effect: "blind",   
             duration: 500    
         }
     });
});
```

As you can see this dialog contains 2 buttons implemented by 2 input tag, these:

```
<td style="text-align: right">
    <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Annulla" onclick="javascript:window.close()"/>

    <input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Rifiuta" onclick="rifiuta()"/>
</td>
```

When the user click on the **Annulla** button I want that the dialog is closed.

Actually I tryied to use the **window.close()** function but it can't work.

I think that to cloe this dialog I have to use the same event that is performed when the user use the **ESC** keyboard button that close the dialog with a simple animation.

But I really have no idea about how do it. Can you help me to do it?

Tnx

Comment: I think you want .dialog( "close" ); See jQuery dialog documentation under sections "buttons" and "hide" for example code. [jQuery Dialog](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$("#dialogReject").dialog( "close" );`

For more info, read https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

To bind it, change

```
<input class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Annulla" onclick="javascript:window.close()"/>
```

to

```
<input id="closeDialog" class="bottone" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="Annulla"/>
```

and add this after: `$("#dialogReject").dialog({ [..your code..] });`

```
$("#closeDialog").click(function(){
    $("#dialogReject").dialog( "close" );
})
```

Comment: mmm where have I to put it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen for an event in your javascript file.

First set an id to your close button, i'm using #closeButton here :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    larghezza = '950px';
        lunghezza = '470px';
        lunghezza2 = '530px';
    $("#dialogReject").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                //width:'335px',
                width:'600px',
                modal: true,
                show: {        effect: "blind",        duration: 500      },
                hide: {        effect: "blind",        duration: 500      }

     });

    $("#closeButton").click(function(){
        $("#dialogReject").close();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answer was given by Alex and kaz 
 $("#dialogReject").close();

Or you can use button which can be created through jquery also

```
  buttons: {Rifiuta: funstion()
            {
            rifiuta()
            },
              Annulla: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
```

For reference:
https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

```
    $( "#dialogReject" ).dialog({
 autoOpen: open,
            //width:'335px',
            width:'600px',
            modal: true,
            show: {        effect: "blind",        duration: 500      },
            hide: {        effect: "blind",        duration: 500      },
  buttons: {Rifiuta: funstion()
            {
            rifiuta()
            },
          Annulla: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```